# InfoPath 2013 and SharePoint Foundation 2013

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, infopath, forms-services

Can I use InfoPath Form Services in SharePoint Foundation 2013?

I searched online they have given help only forSharePoint Foundation 2010 with InfoPath Forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know InfoPath is a SharePoint Server 2013 Enterprise Feature only.

See here: http://blog.blksthl.com/2013/01/14/sharepoint-2013-feature-comparison-chart-all-editions/

[image]